# Swift 3 webview touch event

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to include a webview touch event in my swift 3 application, but remains unsuccessful while doing so.

I tried to use toucheBegan and touchesEnd events by following examples found while googling. Can someone past a snippet or a  link with swift 3

I am trying by this way

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}
```

but not working. I don't know how to integrate webview in it.

Comment: you can show what you have tried prior ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing `UITapGestureRecognizer` for all kind of views will be a workaround solution try with that.

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: "handleSingleTap:")      
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1                 
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
} 

func handleSingleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //Do something here with the gesture 
}
```

For touch began and touch end try with that code by overriding native methods.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event) 
let touch: UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch
if (touch.view == yourView){ 
   println("touchesBegan | This is an ImageView") 
 }else{ 
   println("touchesBegan | This is not an ImageView") 
 } 
}
```

touchend func.

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set, withEvent event: UIEvent) { 
   super.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event) 
   let touch: UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch 

   if (touch.view == yourView){
      printing("touchesEnded | This is an ImageView")
    }
   else{ 
      println("touchesEnded | This is not an ImageView")
    } 
}
```

Comment: code sure works, what you need to achieve by implement touch begin and touch end.